# Prove that there is a perfect cube between n and 3n for any integer n≥10

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, problem-solving

I was solving one of the Number theory problems from Mathematical Olympiad Challenges,
And the problem goes like :

Prove that there is a perfect cube between $n$ and $3n$ for any integer $n\geq 10$.

And experimenting I found that if $a^3$ lies b/w, $n$ and $3n$ ($n≥19$) then it also lies b/w $m$ and $3m$ , where $m<a^3$ ;
Therefore if the statement to be proved is true then taking $m=a^3$ implies b/w $m$ and $3m$ there lies $(a+1)^3$ i.e., $(a+1)^3$ lies b/w $a^3$ and $3a^3$ ,
So therefore to prove this we need to prove an equivalent inequality i.e.,

$n^3 <(n+1)^3 < 3n^3$ ; for any integer $n\geq10$

Comment: To prove $(n+1)^3 < 3n^3$ for all $n \geq 10$, observe that $n+1 \leq n + \frac{1}{10}n = \frac{11}{10}n$ and hence $(n+1)^3 \leq (\frac{11}{10}n)^3 = \frac{1331}{1000}n^3 < 3n^3$.

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Math_lover Welcome to Math SE. FYI, using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%243n%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24n%5Cge%2010%24&p=1), I found the AoPS thread [Perfect cube](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1405739p7872748).

Comment: @VTand this was a beautiful approach for proving the inequality..thaks for it

Answer (score 3):

Let us assume $n < k^3 < 3n$

This is true for $n=10, k = 3$.

Now by construction, we know there is cube in $k^3 - 1 < k^3 < 3k^3 - 3$
So we are covered for all $n$ from $n$ to $k^3 - 1$.

Now we just have to prove that $k^3 < (k+1)^3 < 3k^3$

Obviously $k^3 < (k+1)^3$ and the second inequality is true for $k \ge 3$

And we can continue this forever.

Comment: yes. I assumed $ n \ge 10$. Now corrected. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to prove the statement using contradiction by assuming, on the contrary that there ***exists*** a natural number $n \geq  10$ such that there is no perfect cube lying between $n$ and $3n$. Then for any natural number $k$,

$$ k^{3}<n<3 n<(k+1)^{3},$$
which implies that for ***all*** natural number $k$,

$$(k+1)^{3}-k^3>2n \Leftrightarrow 3k^2+3k+(1-2n)>0 \tag*{(*)} $$

Using that fact that $$\Delta_{(*)}<0 ,$$
we have $$
9<12(1-2 n)\Leftrightarrow n<\frac{1}{8} ,
$$

which contradicts to that $n\geq 10$ and hence prove the statement.

More precisely, the statement is true for any $n\in N \backslash\{1,2,8,9\}.$

Comment: What does $\Delta_{(*)}$ mean?

Comment: @PeterPhipps Presumably, it's the discriminant of the quadratic polynomial $3k^2 + 3k + (1 - 2n)$. The value of this polynomial is always positive only if its discriminant is negative, i.e., $3^2 - 4 \cdot 3 \cdot (1-2n) < 0$. This is equivalent to the inequality $9 < 12(1-2n)$ in the original answer.

Comment: @VTand Thank you for that.